# Looking for Data science training with Python

Tags: machine-learning, python

Looking for Data science training with Python in Bangalore location with real time scenarios & Project preparations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of great resources out there online, many free. I personally have experience with and recommend edX and DataCamp

https://www.datacamp.com/courses/intro-to-python-for-data-science

https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-python-data-science-microsoft-dat208x-5

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for answering it as I don't have required reputation to comment.

This site is meant for problem discussion and possible approaches to solve them. It is not portal to ask the question you have asked. You can google for the problem that you have asked and I am sure you will get an answer. You should have read the instruction and read community guidelines before asking this question.